# Slow Animated SVG Load on Webpage

Tags: html, svg

I have an animated svg file (4MB) that loads at the top of my web page. The SVG file itself is being managed by imgix. The problem is that it loads a little slower than the rest of the top elements.

I've seen posts say that I should embed the SVG in my HTML but when I do that my HTML size goes from 20KB to 11MB. More importantly, the entire page then takes quite long to load.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Sure, make the SVG file simpler and therefore smaller.

Comment: I don't think removing SVG elements is a viable option. Is there a compression method that can be used as an alternative?

Comment: That would only affect network transfer and that's likely not an issue given that the browser probably caches the file anyway.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it is impossible to get a relatively large SVG file to load quickly?

Comment: You could always use/buy a faster computer. It depends on the SVG of course, but generally size does correlate with rendering time. Why would you think it wouldn't? If you have a large raster image or a big html page it will take longer too.

Comment: Maybe you could load parts of the SVG dynamically just like you would do with HTML using JavaScript.